# SQLAlchemy set parents column value

Tags: sqlalchemy

Wanting a `Base` which defines a `version` column, and then populate that `version` in inheriting classes.

the idea is something like:

**my_declarative_base.py:**

```
def declarative_base():
    Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

    class MyBase(Base):
        __abstract__ = True

        version = Column(VARCHAR)

    return MyBase
```

**__init__.py**

```
from {path.to}.my_declarative_base import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

**my_model.py:**

```
from {path.to} import Base

class MyModel_1(Base):
    col_1 = Column(...)
    col_2 = Column(...)
    ...

    version = "v3.3.3"

class MyModel_2(Base):
    col_11 = Column(...)
    col_22 = Column(...)
    ...

    version = "v33.33-alpha"
```

(as expected, trying this wouldn't work)

the focus is that setting the version in the inheriting classes is simple and straightforward, like assigning a variable (that is, I would not want `version` declaration to have `default` property set to a callable, where each inheriting class would have to know it has to implement, or other solutions of this "framework" style; looking for something plain, simple, clear and straightforward).

Ideas how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It’s not exactly clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to have each row in the database contain the version string?

Comment: @rfkortekaas, yes. a set of tables, where a record has a version.